# Migrating db from pgsql 9.5 to 12.4 via pg_dumpall does not include all tables

Tags: postgresql, pg-dumpall

I am trying to migrate three databases to a new server (Linux centos 8 - pgsql 12.4)

So I am using "pg_dumpall" and target the old server - backups are getting created, then I am using psql to import the dump.

I noticed that in one db there are tables missing that have a custom schema name "RRJ_DES" - these are tables which are missing after importing the dump on the 12.4 Server. All other tables have "public" schema, and these are there.
I am definitely using the superuser with all permissions when taking the dump.

Any idea? I am a bit new to postgres...

Comment: Did you get any errors?  Are you sure they are actually missing, rather than just no longer in your search_path?  If you set search_path in the postgresql.conf, that change will not be present in the restored database unless you did something to make it happen.

Comment: You´re right- There is a diffrence... on the old server there is "RRJ_DES" in the search path. "SHOW search_path;" does not have it in on the new 12.4 - this could be the reason?